# How to automate taking full memory dump from Azure webapp with parameters

Tags: azure, kudu, memory-dump

what are the alternatives if I want to take a crash dump from an Azure webapp. I've tried with adplus but it causes a huge performance hit and can't be used. Are there any other alternatives? I need to specify that the memory dump should be taken when the site crashes like in adplus where you can set "-crash".

I've heard of crash diagnoser but that's not an alternative unfortunately.

/Joe

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the Kudu site for your Azure webapp service, and Go to the Debug console and capture the dump.

Create a directory for the dumps and run this command. In this case, add `-e` parameter for exception or crash when your Azure webapp crash. You can refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/02/02/how-to-get-a-full-memory-dump-in-azure-app-services/) for detailed steps first.

```
d:\devtools\sysinternals\procdump  -accepteula -ma <PID> -e
```

References: [ProcDump v9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump)

Comment: Is my reply helpful?

Comment: will procdump cause any performance issues? also, can you make it run in the background until the process actually crash?

Comment: The procdump will monitor the related PID, wouldn't cause a performance issue, but we need to keep the cmd window.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this and see if it will work or not without affecting performance and get back to you.

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue on an azure website by starting the procdump with operator -e but when killing the w3wp process there is no dump created. Any ideas? I get:
The process has exited.
Dump count not reached.

Comment: "kill process" is regard as "process unexpected terminated", not process crash/exception. you could use -t to replace -e for testing "kill process" .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178521/discussion-between-joe-and-nancy-xiong-msft).

Comment: Yes, -t parameter seems also couldn't be used for testing "kill process". but  as i have said, we couldn't use "kill process" to simulate crash/exception, it is hard to replicate the issue manully. You could test -e parameter whether affecting performance, and you could create a general dump without -e parameter to verify that the dump file is normal。You could also refer to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2017/05/08/azure-app-service-generating-memory-dumps-on-first-chance-exception-using-procdump/)

Comment: I used the -e and I generated a stackoverflow on an azure website but unfortunately it still didn't caputre a bug. It ended with The process ha exited. Dump count not reached.

Comment: Based on current situation, I suggest [contacting the Azure Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4026305/sql-contact-microsoft-azure-support) to get deeper and effective solution in this issue.